# IntelliJ project with sub projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a way to create a gradle java project in IntelliJ with a client and server side that share a class library? Something similar to how Visual Studio allows multiple sub projects that can have their own .exe build for each and a .dll for the library.

Example:
+ Project 
    - Client (Separate .jar built)
    - Server (Separate .jar built)
    - ClassLibrary (used by Client and Server)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use File | New... | Module action and select Gradle type for the new module.

By default IDE will add this Gradle module to your project as a child via `include '<project-name>'` directive in `settings.gradle` file.

Then in your main/parent project `build.gradle` script you can add this Gradle project as a dependency: `implementation project(':<project-name>')`. See Gradle documentation for [Project lib dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies) for more information.